# Accessing classes in default package in a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, package

I have a Java application and the Java files are in a package called `app`. I have added a JAR file to the classpath. All classes in the JAR file are in the default package.

From my Java application I can't access classes of this JAR file. Only if I put my application files in the default package, then I can see the classes in the JAR file. Why is that?

Comment: Giovanni has probably moved on, but I am having the same problem. I am using eclipse and have added the jar files to the java build path. I imagine they are in someway under the default package, because only files in the default package can access methods in the jar file. Is there a way to add jar files so that all packages can have access to the jar files through Project>Properties>JavaBuildPath or by changing the .classpath file?

Answer (score 4):

You can no longer `import` from default packages. (You used to be able to in Sun's early javac implementations, but this was not allowed for in the language spec.) Obvious solutions:

- Don't use the default package, if possible. Move all classes, interfaces and enums into named packages. [good]
- Move your packaged classes into the default package. [bad]
- Access the classes via reflection. [terrible]

Comment: I have tryed to make a jar with the classes I need into a package, but I can't see the classes from my application

Comment: @Giovanni I think you are going to need a simple but complete example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in the default package are not visible to classes inside a package.

When classes are in a different package, then you basically need to `import` classes. But since it's impossible to `import` classes in the default package, the only solution is to put those classes in a package.

Always put classes in a package whenever you want to reuse classes.