# Removing Eclipse package name

Tags: java, eclipse

Why do I get `package name` in the top of the page whenever I try to create a java class?

I have written some codes in the past using Eclipse but it had no package name like this. I am just wondering why?

You can see the following.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your IDE window?

Comment: I think i can not post picture due to low reputation i have.

Comment: Isn't your java class placed in `asd` package? I agree with @XOR, posting screenshot of your project structure and your class localization would be helpful. You don't need to post it in question. Just share link to some well-known image hosting server (we can later add this image to your question for you if needed).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7xqrzy

Comment: You know, there should be `print screen` button on your keybord which will let you capture current state of your screen. You can paste that state to any image editor and save it as image. No need to use camera :) Anyway as you can see your `Ex1.java` file is in package named `asd` so everything is as it should be (if `java` is placed inside package we need to add name of package at start of that file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Java classes have specified their address in the beginning of the document. They say

```
package package_name;
```

If the class is in the default package (directly in 'src' folder), then there is no package written in the beginning of the class...

You can see here, and try on your own:

[image: class in package]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your class in contained in the package named `asd`. This is also shown on the left hand side: project "asd" / package "asd" / Class "Ex1.java"

If you want to get rid of the package, you need to move your class to "default package". Right click on the class -> Refactor -> Move -> choose `(default package)`

**However, I would recommend to work with packages and name them properly. Putting classes into "default package" is considered bad practice.**

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in *package explorer*

[image]

you placed your class inside `asd` package. This happened when you created your class via `File`->`New`->`Class` wizard. If you don't specify any package then by default it will use project name.

[image]

So when you confirm such configuration such setup `Ex1.java` will be placed inside `asd` folder (package), which means that your code will need at its start information about name of package.

If you don't want to have this `package asd;` line you can for instance

- clean that section from wizard when you create package,
- or even remove that line from your code and when Eclipse will ask you how to fix this situation

  1. place cursor in line with problem (first line)
  2. select `Edit`->`Quick fix`, or press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)
  3. and chose `Move Ex1.java to default package`.

But ***you should avoid using default package***. For instance when you export classes from your project to Jar file [you will not be able to import them in new projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685358/accessing-classes-in-default-package-in-a-jar-file).

For more info about packages visit official tutorial:

- [What Is a Package?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html)
- [Lesson: Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html)

Comment: When creating a new class, you can delete the suggested package name and leave it empty to place the new class into "default package" initially.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes, that is true, but it is better to have classes inside packages so instead of removing that package name, I would simply rename it to something more descriptive. It is useful for instance if we want to create Jar file and reuse our classes in other projects.

Comment: Of course, it is better to use packages! But the question's headline is "Removing Eclipse package name". ;)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Fair enough, will update my answer :)

Comment: thank you, by default eclipse put my java class inside a package and i was not aware of that.